# Self-Relationship query with oracle (children doesn't have the same father)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to work on a query involving a self-relationship table.

I have these rows:

```
ID    Parent_ID

1     null
2     1
3     2
4     3
.
.
.
```

The "children" doesn't share the same father. Each 'father' only have one child.
I have the ID of the last 'child'. (For example, i have the ID = 4)..I'd like to get this:

```
  1     null
  2     1
  3     2
  4     3
```

How can i retrieve these rows, given that the Parent Id may not be in a sequential order.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as 'in a single query' this might be a bit complex... it'd help if we had a larger idea of what you were aiming for, but a recursive function in your surrounding code could make a simple series of calls to the database that would get you the structure you need.  If that won't work... do you have a maximum depth of some sort?

Comment: My friend said that the depth could go as far as it could go...i can't work with a fixed depth...

Comment: Well, then, will a recursive function breaking it into a series of database calls work?

Comment: Oracle supports recursion using CONNECT BY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle supports recursive queries:

```
SELECT t.id, t.parent_id
FROM t 
START WITH t.id = 4
CONNECT BY PRIOR t.parent_id = t.id
```

sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1cfbf/6).

Comment: From this, you can also select the level and pad it using `lpad` to get your queries to return like trees. It's useful in hierarchical and ancestry queries.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a recursive cte:

```
with cte (id, parent_id) as (
  select id, parent_id
  from yourtable
  where id = 4
  union all
  select y.id, y.parent_id
  from yourtable y
    join cte c on y.id = c.parent_id
  )
select * from cte order by id
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c9b2/2)